# Rails Expire action using regex expression with Memcache

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

Iam working on a Rails application and have integrated caching with memcache using Dalli. Iam working on action caching and expiring cache using sweepers. 
My sweeper code looks like this:

```
class BoardSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Board

  def after_create(board)
    expire_cache(board)
  end

  def expire_cache(board)
   expire_action :controller => :boards, :action => :show, :id => "#{board.id}-#{board.title.parameterize}"
  end

end
```

But I want to delete the cache using regex expression i.e. I want to match the url and delete the cache just like:

*If my board show url's are like:*

```
 "boards/1/likes-collection-of-branded-products.text/javascript"
 "boards/1/likes-collection-of-branded-products.text/html"
```

*Then I want to use the following expression to expire the cache:*

```
 Rails.cache.delete_matched(/boards\/1.*/)
```

But as per the [memcache api doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemCacheStore.html#method-i-read_multi) it doesnt support **delete_matched** method.

Iam sure there should be some way to delete on basis of regex. Please help.

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik the problem with memcached is that there is no simple way of retrieving all keys. that's why there is no such functionality as expiring based on a regular expression.

what you could do:

use a naming convention for your cache keys and simply expire all cache keys that you know of, that might have been created.

this would impose a little overhead by expiring keys that have not been created.

overall, i would not advise you using action-caches. there are good reasons that those got excluded from rails4.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Gibson](http://gibson-db.in/) cache server as your primary cache store, it supports multiple keys invalidation by prefix in O(1) time due to its internal data structure, in your case it would be just a matter of:

```
Rails.cache.delete_matched "boards/1/"
```

An ActiveSupport extension is being developed and will be released in about a week.